# need help finding lost cell phone

Tags: lost-phone

I'm trying to help my father locate his lost android cell phone.  He doesn't know the gmail account info it is connected to, so we cannot locate it that way.  (was set up for him, not his own doing)  Without a gmail account address/username or the 'recovery' info to find that out, is there a way I can help him locate his cell phone???

Answer (score 0):

The reality is no... not unless you had some other tracking software like Where's My Droid or similar installed prior to it going missing/stolen.

Law enforcement generally will not do anything, in order for them to track the device with the carrier requires a court order, and a sub-$1000 device is rarely significant enough to warrant what they have to  get it done, and it is rarely effective anyway.

The best you can do is contact the carrier and report it stolen, which will blacklist the IMEI/MEID and it cannot be activated on most carriers, rendering it worthless.

Unfortunately, this happens a lot, there isn't really any way to recovery the phone unless you just lucky and call it and someone answers and is willing to return it.

It should also be mentioned that if you are somehow able to locate it, if it was truly stolen you should NOT attempt to recover it yourself... the potential of something bad happening is high, contact law enforcement if you are sure you know where the device is located.

Answer (score 0):

With technical cannot. but. with the help of police you can find that. you must know about the IMEI number. check you mobile IMEI number. if you not know imei number,  otherwise, go to the police station and file complaint against your phone. and give last mobile number you have used on that phone. they can track IMEI based on your last mobile number. then , they will track that IMEI number which is currently used by another person. then track him. this technique is used for theft of lost mobile. for this technique the mobile must be switched on.